# jquery Github api

Tags: javascript, jquery, github-api

I'm working on a webpage that I need to display the list of repos by using the github api. But keep get 401 error. Not sure where I was wrong.....
Here is what I have so far:

```
function requestJSON(url, callback) {
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function(xhr) {
    callback.call(null, xhr.responseJSON);
     console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
    //alert('Load was performed.');
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
    alert('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
}
else {
    alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
}
  },
  error: function( req, status, err ) { console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
},
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authCredentials);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');}
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authCredentials);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');}
```

It was my authCredentials issue, miss type.....